# Writing files with Flatworm in Unix System

Tags: java, file, shared-libraries, portability

We've got a weird situation with our Java application, we need to write a flat wile and we decided to use Flatworm java library.
We wrote an enterprise java app that needs to be scheduled on a Unix server. We developed our java application and it executes well on our windows desktop PCs.
When we try to execute our application that use Flatworm library we get a silent error. The application hangs and it doesn't throw any exception. 
So we tried to put a lot of logging information and we understood where it's the problem.

```
fileCreator = new FileCreator(outputData.getConfigMailFile(), outputData.getDownloadFolder() + trackFileName);
            fileCreator.open();
            fileCreator.setRecordSeperator("\n");
            for (MailFile mail : listMails) {
                fileCreator.setBean("mail", mail);
                fileCreator.write("mailRow");
            }
```

The error should be inside the java cicle, when we call these two methods.

```
for (MailFile mail : listMails) {
                    fileCreator.setBean("mail", mail);
                    fileCreator.write("mailRow");
                }
```

We're a bit lost about this problem, we would like to understand at least how to catch this exception. Unix machine that executes the code seems to stop abnormally.
I really appreciate your help.
Thank you

**UPDATE 19/07/2012**

We tried it on linux 3.2 kernel java 1.6 and the program works. It looks like there is something with flatworm that blocks it, we looked in the source of flatworm the application hangs in this part of code:

```
if (beanRef != null)
                        {
                            // Extract property name
                            Object bean = null;
                            String property = "";
                            try
                            {
                                int posOfFirstDot = beanRef.indexOf('.');
                                bean = beans.get(beanRef.substring(0, posOfFirstDot));
                                property = beanRef.substring(posOfFirstDot + 1);
                            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
                            {
                                throw new FlatwormCreatorException("Had trouble parsing : " + beanRef
                                        + " Its format should be <bean_name>.<property_name>");
                            }

                            // Convert to String for output
                            Object value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, property);
                            val = convHelper.convert(type, value, convOptions, beanRef);
                            PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, property, value);
                        } // end beanRef != null
                        // Handle any conversions that need to occur
                        if (val == null)
                        {
                            val = "";
                        }
                        val = convHelper.transformString(val, recElement.getConversionOptions(), recElement
                                .getFieldLength());

                        if (itRecElements.hasNext())
                            bufOut.write(val + delimit);
                        else
                            bufOut.write(val);
```

The other unix where it doesn't work is kernel 2.6 and java 1.6

Comment: did you try it in a different version of java and different version of unix?

Comment: I tried it in a java 1.6 and unix. Anyway the answer is no. I will try it in a linux enviroment and evaluate the result